# Payment Gateway in Android

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway

I am implementing the paymentGateway for the Citrus in my android app. I am getting below error in console.

> 12-22 17:13:03.041: I/chromium(13772): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: paymentResponse is not defined",

source: http://www.palamsilk.com/Webservice/PayResponseIOS.aspx (12)

Below is code of my Webview :

```
private WebView loadwebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.netpayscreen);
        initScreen();
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
        startWebView(url);
    }

    private void initScreen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loadwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    }

    private void startWebView(String url) {

        // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        // When opening a url or click on link

        loadwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            // @Override
            // public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap
            // favicon) {
            // super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            //
            // if (progressDialog == null) {
            // // in standard case YourActivity.this
            // progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NetPayActivity.this);
            // progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            // progressDialog.show();
            // }
            // }

            // If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower
            // not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            // Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NetPayActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                try {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        loadwebview.loadUrl(url);
        loadwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        loadwebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this),
                "Android");

        // Javascript inabled on webview
        // Load url in webview


    }

    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */

        public void paymentResponse(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

My paymentResponse function is never called when payment is done successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed annotation @JavascriptInterface for function paymentResponse